# In Maya, how to find all shells in a UV tile?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm looking for a way in Mel or Python to determine if a particular UV shell crosses across multiple texture tiles in Maya. I know Mudbox has a check for this, but I can't find an easy command for this in Maya in the interface or in script.

One approach I thought of is to compare the shells in each tile and see if any shell appears in more than one tile.

I found a page here someone figured out how to select each UV in a given set of texture tiles, but it operates on UVs, not shells. Here's the page:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=1123235

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a one-liner way to do it.

Here's an example of a method for getting the uv bounding boxes of the shells in Python.  It uses the API to get bounding boxes for all the uv shells in an object (note -- it should be a mesh shape object , I didn't add any checks).

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as api
from math import floor

def get_shells(obj, uvset = ''):
    selected = api.MGlobal.getSelectionListByName(obj)
    node =  selected.getDependNode(0)

    mesh = api.MFnMesh(node)
    howmany, shell_ids = mesh.getUvShellsIds(uvset)
    u_list, v_list = mesh.getUVs()
    shells = []
    for shell_num in range(howmany):
        umin =  vmin = 9999999999999
        umax=  vmax = -9999999999999
        for idx, value in enumerate(shell_ids):
            if value == shell_num:
                umin = min(umin, u_list[idx])
                umax = max(umax, u_list[idx])
                vmin = min(vmin, v_list[idx])
                vmax = max(vmax, v_list[idx])

        shells.append ( (umin, vmin, umax, vmax) ) 

    return shells


print get_shells('pCylinderShape1')
# [(0.3437499701976776, -7.450580596923828e-08, 0.65625, 0.3125), (0.375, 0.3125, 0.6249997615814209, 0.6884398460388184), (0.3437499701976776, 0.6874999403953552, 0.65625, 1.0)]
```

The result is a list of 4-item tuples which are the bounding boxes of the uv shells in the object  stored as `( u min, v min, u max, v max )` .  To catch a tile boundary just check that the minimum and maximum corners of the are the same integer values:

```
 for shell in get_shells('pCylinderShape1'):
     mintile = int(shell[0]), int(shell[1])
     maxtile = int(shell[2]), int(shell[3])
     if mintile != maxtile:
        print "shell crosses UV boundary", shell
```